# Can't reach backend when url base is set

Tags: node.js, reactjs, rest, express, base-path

I have an application built using Express, Mongoose, React and Node. My application is hosted on a location which looks like the following: `https://example.com/app_name` which means that `app_name` is the base path for all of the static assets.

I'm using Webpack and setting `publicPath` to `https://example.com/app_name`. I can reach my static assets just fine, but when I attempt to do a call to my back-end, my requests are being routed to `https://example.com/api/...` instead of `https://example.com/app_name/api/...`.

Is there a way to prefix my endpoint calls so that they use `https://example.com/app_name/api/...` instead of `https://example.com/api/...`through webpack or any other means?

Comment: "my requests are being routed to https://example.com/api/... instead of https://example.com/api/..." Possible typo?

Comment: I don't see a problem with the way your paths are defined, it would be silly to have your api served from a static assets directory. Now when you say you "can't reach backend" what do you mean? You might have CORS-related issues which need to be specifically dealt with. Could you post your server.js source?

Comment: Or do you mean `/app_name` is the root location of your entire project? Your question is ambiguous.

Comment: `app_name` is not a public directory. The application sits behind a proxy that passes traffic from `https://example.com/app_name` to the server where my application is running.